# Pass Id to a Onclick Function JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid.I need to take some Id to the OnClick function.In my scenario i wanted to get BasicId to the OnClick function.

MyCode

```
 function grid() {
    //JqGrid
    $('#griddata').html('<table class="table" id="jqgrid"></table>')
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({

        url: '/Admin/GetBasicData/',

        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        //columns names
        colNames: ['BasicId','Images'],
        //columns model
        colModel: [

                    { name: 'BasicId', index: 'BasicId', resizable: false },


                     {
                         name: 'Images',
                         width: 120,

                         formatter: function () {
                             return "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' onclick='OpenDialog()' style='margin-left:30%'>View</button>";
                         }
                     },

//Some Code here
```

Open Dialog Function

```
function OpenDialog(BasicId)
{
//Some code here
}
```

Comment: @Oleg pls cehck your answers comment section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onclick='OpenDialog.call(this, event)'` instead of `onclick='OpenDialog()'`. You will have `this` inside of `OpenDialog` initialized to the clicked `<button>` and the `event.target`. Thus your code could be like the following

```js
function OpenDialog (e) {
    var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"),
        $grid = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid-btable"),
        basicId = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId");

    // ...

    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

One more option is even better: you don't need to specify any `onclick`. Instead of that you can use `beforeSelectRow` [callback](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) of jqGrid:

```
beforeSelectRow (rowid, e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
        colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        basicId = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId");
    if (colModel[iCol].name === "Images") { // click in the column "Images"
        // one can make additional test for 
        //   if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "button")
        // to be sure that it was click to the button
        // and not the click on another part of the column
        OpenDialog(rowid);
        return false; // don't select the row - optional
    }
}
```

The main advantages of the last approach: one don't need to make any additional binding (every binding get memory resources and it take time). There are already exist on `click` handler in the grid and one can use it. It's enough to have one click handler because of event bubbling. The `e.target` provide us still full information about the clicked element.

Comment: Can i know how to get the QuestionnaireId instead of row id  in this code var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");

Comment: @UDP: You mean probably the content of `BasicId` column? You can use `var basicId = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId");` after you have `rowid`. In general you should consider to add `key: true` property to the definition of `BasicId` column if the values of the column are unique. It will inform jqGrid the use the value from the column as `id` attribute of the row (rowid). So you will have `BasicId === rowid`.

Comment: I'm sorry i have a doubt.I use below Code to get BasicId.. but it shows me `false`  Code : var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
        var basicId = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId");

Comment: @UDP: What solution you use? With `onclick='OpenDialog()'` or with `beforeSelectRow`? I inserted the code fragments for both cases. If you use  `onclick='OpenDialog()'` then `this` is the clicked button and `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");` is correct, but `$(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId")` incorrect because you can use with grid only and not with the button.  I shown above that you can use `$grid = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid-btable")` to find the grid in which the button exist and then use `basicId = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "BasicId")`.

Comment: @UDP: If you would add `key: true` in `BasicId` column (you can use it only if you have different values in every row) then `rowid` will be already `"BasicId"` and you will not need to do this.

Comment: I use `onclick='OpenDialog()' ` solution.But  `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");` shows me the rowid NOT Basic id.

Answer (score 0):

Writing js event in your buttons html is not a good idea, its against 'un-obtrusive javasript' principle. You can instead add a click event on the entire grid in the `render` function and in the callback, filter out based on whether the button was clicked.

//not sure of the syntax of jqgrid, but roughly:

```
render: function(){
    $('#jqgrid').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
        if($(e.target).hasClass('btn-warning')){
            var tr = $(e.target).parent('tr');
            //retrieve the basicId from 'tr'
            OpenDialog(/*pass the basicId*/)
        }
    })
}
```